# How to get random post link to iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, blogger

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to get a random post from a blog under a category, and I want to display that post with iframe. So this is a code that gets a random post from the rss feed of a specified category and goes to it when you click on random post button:

```
function showLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var entry = feed.entry[0];
    for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j) {
        if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate") {
            window.location = entry.link[j].href;
        }
    }
}
function fetchLuck(luck){
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/categoryname?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
function readLucky(root){
    var feed = root.feed;
    var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
    var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
    luckyNumber++;
    fetchLuck(luckyNumber);
}
function feelingLucky(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/categoryname?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=readLucky';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

<a href="#randompost" onclick="feelingLucky()">RANDOM POST</a>
```

The "a" element at the bottom is a RANDOM POST button, and it starts onclick feelinglucky() function, then goes to the random post it generates, when you click on it. So it's a simple random post button for Blogger. But I want this: I will click on RANDOM POST button, the code will select a random post from the feed, fetches the URL of that post. Then it will generate an iframe whose src is the URL that was fetched.

But I don't understand how I can get the URL of the selected random post from this code. It just goes automatically to the post it selected.

Can you please be easy on me? I'm pretty new.

Comment: Change `window.location=` to `myiframe.src=`

Comment: whenever in the code is called function `showLucky`? I suppose that's happen by  `script`. Had you ever debug the code before you pasted it?

Comment: @W92 I'm new to JS as I've stated in the post.

Comment: @KerkaFyah OK, here's some advice, you can't pick up random script from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/w886eKxH) and expect it to be functional. We expect certain things from OP (that's you Original Poster): 1) a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 2) The code of what you have already tried. I 'm not going to vote to close your question, nor downvote you, but I can't speak for everyone.